# React native SSL certificate

Tags: ssl, react-native

I want to secure api, used by react native app.

If authorisation header is sent user can read a request and access data so to avoid this I want to use SSL certificate for client and server.

Now if I place certificate in asests folder it will be accessible to the users whoever download the apk.

Is it possible for the user to get the client side certificate from asests. If yes how can it be avoided.

Comment: got the answer here. https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/180687/client-ssl-certificates-in-a-react-native-mobile-app-can-be-accessed-or-not?noredirect=1#comment350457_180687